# Create "blinking" caret effect for javascript "typing"

Tags: javascript, html

So I currently have some javascript code that creates a "typing" effect. During the typing, there is a caret at the end that mimics the caret type when typing into a console. When the typing has finished, I'd like for the caret to begin blinking, just as it would within a console. Here is the code used for it:

html:

```
<div id="typedtext"></div>
```

javascript:

```
// set up text to print, each item in array is new line
var arrText = new Array(
"This is an example of some,", 
"typed text."
);
var speed = 60; // time delay of print out
var index = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var arrLength = arrText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var scrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines
 
var textPos = 0; // initialise text position
var contents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var row; // initialise current row
 
function typewriter()
{
 contents =  ' ';
 row = Math.max(0, index-scrollAt);
 var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");
 
 while ( row < index ) {
  contents += arrText[row++] + '<br />';
 }
 destination.innerHTML = contents + arrText[index].substring(0, textPos) + "█";
 if ( textPos++ == arrLength ) {
  textPos = 0;
  index++;
  if ( index != arrText.length ) {
   arrLength = arrText[index].length;
   setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
  }
 } else {
  setTimeout("typewriter()", speed);
 }
}

typewriter();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a few CSS scripts to add blinking effect to the caret. Move the `█` inside a `<span>` and add `.blink` class to it.

```js
// set up text to print, each item in array is new line
var arrText = new Array(
  "This is an example of some,",
  "typed text."
);
var speed = 60; // time delay of print out
var index = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var arrLength = arrText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var scrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines

var textPos = 0; // initialise text position
var contents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var row; // initialise current row

function typewriter() {
  contents = ' ';
  row = Math.max(0, index - scrollAt);
  var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");

  while (row < index) {
    contents += arrText[row++] + '<br />';
  }
  destination.innerHTML = contents + arrText[index].substring(0, textPos) + "<span class='blink'>█<span>";
  if (textPos++ == arrLength) {
    textPos = 0;
    index++;
    if (index != arrText.length) {
      arrLength = arrText[index].length;
      setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
    }
  } else {
    setTimeout("typewriter()", speed);
  }
}

typewriter();
```

```css
.blink {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="typedtext"></div>
```